# how to extract part of a sentence that ends in a word but only up to a certain amount of words to the left. regex re2

Tags: regex, re2

I have the following regex https://regex101.com/r/6orbpa/1

```
^ho..ital\s+(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5}$
```

it extracts any senetence that starts with the word
hospital OR
hopital
and only includes the sentence if it has up to 5 words to the right.

How do I modify the the regex to make it work from when the words ENDS in
hospital OR
hopital
and includes up to 5 words to the left?

Comment: Maybe just moving the group to the start will do? `^(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5}ho..ital$`

Comment: You may try: `/^(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b *){1,5}hos?pital$/im`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z_']+ +){1,5}hos?pital$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DSwIsb/2). In case you are not using multiline texts, you may replace the literal space with `\s` in the pattern.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z_']+ +){1,5}` - one to five occurrences of

  - `[a-zA-Z_']+` - one or more letters, underscores or `'` chars
  - `+` - one or more spaces
- `hos?pital` - `hospital` or `hopital`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I am trying to get a modified version of your solution working where I am using different language translations for university. 
It only picks up the first word. 

`code`
^(universidad|university|universita|universitat)\s+(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5}$
`code`
https://regex101.com/r/cQ9TLk/1
what am I doing wrong, I can create a new question if you prefer?

Comment: @dpl Not sure what you exactly need, if you need to capture the whole pattern use `^((?:universidad|university|universita|universitat)\s+(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5})$` and if you need to just match, use `^(?:universidad|university|universita|universitat)\s+(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5}$`

Comment: @WS both seem to work, brilliant.

Comment: @WS I have added a version where i can match the university combinations at the end of a string 
 [link] (https://regex101.com/r/tKQhUD/1)

**((?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z_']+\b)[ ]*){1,5}(?:universidad|university|universita|universitat))$**

I'm trying to get it to also work where the university comes in the middle of a string 

 For example for the string "fukuoka university chikushi hospital kyushu japan"
extract only 
"fukuoka university chikushi hospital kyushu"  (A total of 5 words.)